# WTForm will not validate

Tags: flask-wtforms

I have been following the Udemy course on Flask (https://www.udemy.com/python-flask-course/) where the instructor shows how to use WTForms. I am trying to replicate this, but fails to get it to validate the form.

The form is defined in the file admin/form.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import validators, StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import EmailField

class TestForm(Form):
data = StringField('Data', [validators.Required()])
```

The database model is defined in admin/models.py

```
from wtform_test import db

class TestData(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(4))

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Test %r>' % self.data
```

and finally the route is defined in admin/views.py

```
from wtform_test import app
from admin.models import TestData
from admin.form import TestForm
from flask import redirect, url_for, sessions

@app.route('/add_test_data', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def add_test_data():
    form = TestForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            test_data = TestData(form.data)
            db.session.add(test_data)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            return "Could not validate form"
```

When I run this, I always end up with "Could not validate form". I don't get any other error messages, so I am at a loss on where to start looking.

Comment: where is your form?? show your form...its a important part to check this

Comment: Sorry, I made a copy paste mistake and added the code for views.py where the form.py should go. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem. In the above code, there was no rendering of the form. This should be done by changing the app route for add_test_data to the following:

```
@app.route('/add_test_data', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def add_test_data():
    form = TestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        test_data = TestData(form.data)
        return "Success!"
    else:
        return render_template('add_test_data.html', form=form)
```

and then to add the html form as add_test_data.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Enter test data{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
      <h3>Test data</h3>
      {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
      <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('add_test_data') }}" role="form">

          {{ render_field(form.data, class='form-control') }}

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
      </form>
  </div>
```